# Objective-C – Delegate is dealloced?

Tags: objective-c, delegates, uiviewcontroller

I have a view controller that lists some data in an `UITableView`. To get the data downloaded I use `ASIHTTPRequest` which methods I have put in another class.

In my view controller I have setup the appropriate delegates to handle the data that is being retrieved from `ASIHTTPRequest`. So from my view controller in `- viewDidLoad` I alloc and init my class that holds the `ASIHTTPRequest` methods like so:

```
self.officesParser = [[[OfficesParser alloc] init] autorelease]; // retained property
```

Then in `- viewDidAppear:` I call `[officesParser downloadOffices];`

My `- downloadOffices` method looks like this:

```
- (void)downloadOffices {

    // 1. Downloaded offices.json
    NSURL *officesUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/example.json"];
    ASIHTTPRequest *officesRequest = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:officesUrl];

    // Always ask the server if there is new content available, 
    // If the request fails, use data from the cache even if it should have expired.
    [officesRequest setCachePolicy:ASIAskServerIfModifiedCachePolicy|ASIFallbackToCacheIfLoadFailsCachePolicy];

    // Store the cache permanently
    [officesRequest setCacheStoragePolicy:ASICachePermanentlyCacheStoragePolicy];

    [officesRequest setTag:1];

    OfficesViewController *vc = [[OfficesViewController alloc] init];
    [officesRequest setDelegate:vc];
    [vc release];
    [officesRequest startAsynchronous];
}
```

Everytime after calling the `[officesParser downloadOffices]` method I get:

```
*** -[OfficesViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6a2f6c0
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `vc` to be delegate for `officesRequest`, however, after you allocate and initialize `vc` and set it to be the delegate, you immediately release it. Please note that delegate properties are usually `assign`, not `retain`. You are then responsible for keeping your delegate object in existence until no longer needed. So, if you plan to send messages to it in a near future, you can't immediately release it.

Comment: So what says in this post is "wrong" then? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924484/how-to-set-a-delegate-in-a-different-class/3924570#3924570

Comment: @Peter Warbo: Yes, that other question does't handle memory management correctly (unless it's a retaining property).

Comment: @Peter Warbo: Well, if it is released immediately I wouldn't expect it to work. But I checked the documentation for NSXMLParser (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and it says the following in the setDelegate instance method: "delegate: An object that is the new delegate. It is not retained."

Comment: So, how would I properly handle my vc object memory-wise? Should I `autorelease` it?

Comment: That is up to you, really. But sometimes `autorelease` might be too soon. One thing you could do is set `vc` to another property that has a retain policy (you would then place a release call in -dealloc).

Comment: I'm curious though. Because in my `vc` I have a property for the `OfficesParser`. And in the `OfficesParser` I have a property for the `vc`. Will there not be like some kind of weird infinite recursion?

Comment: Yes, probably, and the delegate pattern doesn't like that. Its hard to  say how you should set up things, since I can't see the whole code. But brush up a bit on delegation patterns, and it should become clear to you.